# Why am I receiving Error 400 BAD Request when sending data to online hosting?

Tags: java, android, rest

I'm developing an Android software where it passes the data from mobile to Web via REST API Post method, I'm currently encountering BAD Request when I'm sending a parameter "5%5%". I tried to send it to my localhost using XAMPP and it doesn't give "ERROR 400 Bad Request"

This is how I send my data

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jParser.makeRequest("POST", "http://"+ MyHelper.getStrOnline()+MyHelper.getUrlUpload(), params);
```

This is the code I got from some other posts on how to send data to RESTful API

```
public JSONObject makeRequest(String method, String url, Map<String, String> stringMap) throws IOException, JSONException {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    JSONObject jOBJ = null;

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) makeURLConnectionRequest(method, url, stringMap);

    InputStream inputStream;
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000000);
    // get stream

    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    } else {
        inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
    }
    // parse stream
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String temp, response = "";

    while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        response += temp;
    }

    jOBJ = new JSONObject(response);

    return jOBJ;
}

public URLConnection makeURLConnectionRequest(String method, String apiAddress, Map<String, String> stringMap) throws IOException {
    URL url = null;

    url = new URL(apiAddress);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    String requestBody ="";
    if(stringMap.size()!=0) {
        requestBody = buildPostParameters(stringMap);
    }
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000000);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000000);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(!method.equals("GET"));
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
    writer.write(requestBody);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    outputStream.close();
    urlConnection.connect();
    return urlConnection;
}
```

Comment: it depends on how your REST API validate the incoming parameter

Comment: Does the REST API change its function/way depending on where it is? cause it's working perfectly when I'm testing in my local network via XAMPP.